What are all the end times Bible passages (from the canonical books)?
Until now I have found the following end times Bible passages:

Daniel 7,8,10,11,12
Joel 2:28-32
Matthew 24
Mark 13
Luke  21:5-36
2 Peter 3:1-13
1 Corinthians 15:12-58
1 Thessalonians 4:13-18
1 Thessalonians 5:1-11
2 Thessalonians 2:1-12
1 Timothy 4:1-5
2 Timothy 3:1-9
Revelation 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22

Are there any others?

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  Please take our Tour to understand how we are different to other sites, and what sort of questions are allowed: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

By "canonical books", I assume you are referring to Biblical Canon, but which one? Protestant? RCC? One of the flavors of EO? Other?

I would add Job 40 and 41, about Behemoth and Leviathan. Behemoth is considered by many the beast from the land, while Leviathan is the beast from the sea of Revelation 13.
Then I would add Proverbs 30:4.
Who has ascended to heaven and come down?
    Who has gathered the wind in his fists?
Who has wrapped up the waters in a garment?
    Who has established all the ends of the earth?
What is his name, and what is his son's name?
    Surely you know!

Jesus ascended to heaven after his resurrection, so the phrase "come down" must mean his return at his second coming.
You might as well add the whole Gospel of John. The seven signs in John each match key events in Revelation in reverse order, forming a chiasm. The first sign matches the last event, second matches the next to last, etc. Thus the first sign, the Wedding at Cana, matches the Wedding Supper of the Lamb.
Update:
The Seven signs in John:

Changing Water Into Wine (2:1-11)
Healing the Official's Son (4:46-54)
Healing the paralytic (5:1-18)
Feeding the 5,000 (6:1-14)
Walking on water (6:15-25)
Healing a man born blind (9:1-41)
Raising Lazarus from the dead (11:1-46)

The Seven Thunders in Revelation:
In Revelation 10, we learn that there is an entity that speaks with the voice of seven thunders, but John was told not to write down what they said. However, that particular message by the seven thunders is not the only one in Scripture. If you exclude chapter 10 (which defines the seven thunders), we hear thunder seven more times in Revelation. Each mention of thunder ends a section of Revelation, thus dividing the book into eight parts. There are words or images in each section that mirror a sign from John, in reverse order.

Rev 4:5 -> Raising Lazarus
Rev 6:1-2 -> Healing a man born blind
Rev 8:1-5 -> Walking on water
Rev 11:19 -> Feeding the 5,000
Rev 14:2 -> Healing the paralytic
Rev 16:18 -> Healing the Official's son
Rev 19:6 -> Changing water to wine (the wedding at Cana)

Here are the clues.
A. Lazarus
Lazarus is a type both of Jesus, who rose from the dead, and Christians, who will one day be raised to eternal life. Thus Revelation 1:1 - 4:5 has many references to the resurrection of Christ and the promises given to those who overcome:

4 John to the seven churches that are in Asia:
Grace to you and peace from him who is and who was and who is to come,
and from the seven spirits who are before his throne, 5 and from Jesus
Christ the faithful witness, the firstborn of the dead, and the ruler
of kings on earth. (Revelation 1:4-5)
17 When I saw him, I fell at his feet as though dead. But he laid his
right hand on me, saying, “Fear not, I am the first and the last, 18
and the living one. I died, and behold I am alive forevermore, and I
have the keys of Death and Hades. (Revelation 1:17-18)
7 He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the
churches. To the one who conquers I will grant to eat of the tree of
life, which is in the paradise of God.’ (Revelation 2:7)
10 Do not fear what you are about to suffer. Behold, the devil is
about to throw some of you into prison, that you may be tested, and
for ten days you will have tribulation. Be faithful unto death, and I
will give you the crown of life. 11 He who has an ear, let him hear
what the Spirit says to the churches. The one who conquers will not be
hurt by the second death.’ (Revelation 2:10-11)
5 The one who conquers will be clothed thus in white garments, and I
will never blot his name out of the book of life. I will confess his
name before my Father and before his angels. (Revelation 3:5)

B. Healing a Man born blind
The man that Jesus healed was afflicted with physical blindness. The section of the second thunder is about a world afflicted with spiritual blindness. No one under all creation could read the scroll.

5 Then I saw in the right hand of him who was seated on the throne a
scroll written within and on the back, sealed with seven seals. 2 And
I saw a mighty angel proclaiming with a loud voice, “Who is worthy to
open the scroll and break its seals?” 3 And no one in heaven or on
earth or under the earth was able to open the scroll or to look into
it, 4 and I began to weep loudly because no one was found worthy to
open the scroll or to look into it. 5 And one of the elders said
to me, “Weep no more; behold, the Lion of the tribe of Judah, the Root
of David, has conquered, so that he can open the scroll and its
seven seals.” (Revelation 5:1-5)

And what does Jesus use to read the scroll? Two eyes? No - seven!

6 And between the throne and the four living creatures and among the
elders I saw a Lamb standing, as though it had been slain, with seven
horns and with seven eyes, which are the seven spirits of God sent out
into all the earth. (Revelation 5:6)

C. Walking on Water
When Jesus came to his disciples by night, walking upon the water, what was the weather like? The sea became rough because a strong wind was blowing. (John 6:18)
In Revelation, we see the opposite.

7 After this I saw four angels standing at the four corners of the
earth, holding back the four winds of the earth, that no wind might
blow on earth or sea or against any tree. (Revelation 7:7)

D. Feeding the 5,000
Instead of feeding people, Revelation here speaks of judgment. Revelation 9:1-11 reveals the fifth trumpet judgment, a plague of locusts. Locusts steal all the grain used to make bread, causing thousands to starve, not be fed. Add to that the ministry of the two witnesses, who in Revelation 11:6 "have the power to shut the sky, that no rain may fall during the days of their prophesying". Drought will cause even more people to starve.
And what of the people who find something to eat? Consider John, who was commanded to eat the scroll handed to him:

8 Then the voice that I had heard from heaven spoke to me again,
saying, “Go, take the scroll that is open in the hand of the angel who
is standing on the sea and on the land.” 9 So I went to the angel and
told him to give me the little scroll. And he said to me, “Take and
eat it; it will make your stomach bitter, but in your mouth it will be
sweet as honey.” 10 And I took the little scroll from the hand of the
angel and ate it. It was sweet as honey in my mouth, but when I had
eaten it my stomach was made bitter.  (Revelation 10:8-10)

E. Healing the Paralytic
The paralytic hoped to see the water in the pool be stirred by an angel, then enter the pool first to receive the blessing and be healed. He got Jesus instead. The corresponding part of Revelation has the waters being stirred, but what comes out of them is not a healing angel. First, we see waters used as a murder weapon, as Satan attacks Jesus or the church (or both):

13 And when the dragon saw that he had been thrown down to the earth,
he pursued the woman who had given birth to the male child. 14 But the
woman was given the two wings of the great eagle so that she might fly
from the serpent into the wilderness, to the place where she is to be
nourished for a time, and times, and half a time. 15 The serpent
poured water like a river out of his mouth after the woman, to sweep
her away with a flood. 16 But the earth came to the help of the woman,
and the earth opened its mouth and swallowed the river that the dragon
had poured from his mouth. (Revelation 12:13-16)

Next we see someone or something come up out of the waters healed, but this is no blessing:
13 And I saw a beast rising out of the sea, with ten horns and seven heads, with ten diadems on its horns and blasphemous names on its heads. 2 And the beast that I saw was like a leopard; its feet were like a bear's, and its mouth was like a lion's mouth. And to it the dragon gave his power and his throne and great authority. 3 One of its heads seemed to have a mortal wound, but its mortal wound was healed, and the whole earth marveled as they followed the beast.  (Revelation 13:1-3)
F. Healing the Official's Son
In John 4:48, Jesus challenges the official who appeals to him to heal his son. "Unless you see signs and wonders you will not believe." Remarkably, the man leaves without Jesus accompanying him, trusting the Lord's word that his son was healed. That means that Jesus is really speaking to us. This passage in John makes much of signs, explicitly numbering this the second sign of Jesus in verse 54. In Revelation this reliance upon signs instead of faith is prophesied to be the downfall of humanity. First, it is curious that a reference to the first sign (turning water to wine) is recapitulated in 4:46. Thus we see in Revelation another miracle involving wine:

18 And another angel came out from the altar, the angel who has
authority over the fire, and he called with a loud voice to the one
who had the sharp sickle, “Put in your sickle and gather the clusters
from the vine of the earth, for its grapes are ripe.” 19 So the angel
swung his sickle across the earth and gathered the grape harvest of
the earth and threw it into the great winepress of the wrath of God.
20 And the winepress was trodden outside the city, and blood flowed
from the winepress, as high as a horse's bridle, for 1,600 stadia.
(Revelation 14:18-20)

Then in a rebuke of how easily we fall for false signs:

12 The sixth angel poured out his bowl on the great river Euphrates,
and its water was dried up, to prepare the way for the kings from
the east. 13 And I saw, coming out of the mouth of the dragon and out
of the mouth of the beast and out of the mouth of the false prophet,
three unclean spirits like frogs. 14 For they are demonic spirits,
performing signs, who go abroad to the kings of the whole world, to assemble them for battle on the great day of God the Almighty.
(Revelation 16:12-14)

Jesus turned pure water into wine, but in the above passage the river is dried up. Instead we have demonic spirits, the opposite of pure water, conjuring signs to deceive the world.
G. The Wedding at Cana, turning water into Wine
There are many curses and plagues in Revelation, but few drive the point home like Revelation 18:23, which laments, "and the light of a lamp will shine in you no more, and the voice of bridegroom and bride will be heard in you no more..." The opposite of the joyful wedding at Cana is not a bad wedding, it is no weddings at all - forever. No more families formed. No more children born. It is the end of our species and the extinguishing of all hope.
However, while that seventh thunder ends the times of judgment, it is not the end. The eight section of Revelation begins where the seventh left off:
6 Then I heard what seemed to be the voice of a great multitude,
like the roar of many waters and like the sound of mighty peals of thunder, 
crying out,

“Hallelujah!
For the Lord our God
    the Almighty reigns.
7 Let us rejoice and exult
    and give him the glory,
for the marriage of the Lamb has come,
    and his Bride has made herself ready;
8 it was granted her to clothe herself
    with fine linen, bright and pure”—

for the fine linen is the righteous deeds of the saints.

9 And the angel said to me, 
“Write this: Blessed are those who are invited to 
the marriage supper of the Lamb.” 
And he said to me, “These are the true words of God.” 
(Revelation 19:6-9)

These points of comparison are but fraction of the meaning that connects John and Revelation. For an extended discussion of the Seven Thunders, see this article on my website:
Voice of the Seven Thunders

Would you care to list all seven signs in John (there are disputes about the number of signs) and their correspondence in Revelation, please ? Or a link, perhaps ?

I second Nigel's request. Sounds interesting..

@AndrewShanks - You have your wish! I added to my answer.

@NigelJ - I added to my answer as well as put a link to more information.

Defining 'End Times'In order to answer this question accurately, one must define end times. Many of the passages listed deal with an end, but not the end of the world. Rather, they deal with the end of an age. For example, the end of the Mosaic Age. Remember that the Bible is divided into O.T and N.T. representing the end of the Old Covenant and the beginning of a new one:

In that He saith, "A new covenant", He has made the first old. Now that which decayeth and waxeth old is ready to vanish. (Hebrews 8:13)

And so, many of the alleged signs of the end times deal with the end of an "age" or era (see Matthew 24, End of the Temple Era), not the End of the World. In fact, the Master Teacher, Jesus, taught that there are to be No Signs of the End of the World (Matthew 25). And as the Apostles confirmed, the End of the World is to come like a thief without warning.

But of that Day and Hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven, but My Father only. (Matthew 24:36)


Watch therefore, for ye know not what hour your Lord cometh. (Matthew 24:42; 25:13; 2 Peter 3:10)

ResourcesIt is best to study the verses listed as "End Time" passages and discern which belong to which events. Resources that would help are monographs, commentaries, Roman histories (at the time of Christ), Jewish literature (rabbinical expectations re Messiah), and Greek word studies. You might consult TIMES,THEY ARE A CHANGING, by Raymond Grant, and MATTHEW TWENTY-FOUR by Marcellus Kik; as well as Fairbairn, Sproul, Bass, Edersheim, etc.
